# I can't change my desktop settings

Tags: 14.04, unity, settings

The background settings (right click on wallpaper) seem to be locked. I can't change nothing, not even my wallpaper.

Any ideas?

Comment: The answer to the problem is in http://askubuntu.com/questions/531743/the-gsettings-command-line-tool-doesnt-change-the-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your account have necessary permissions to make changes? You may want to check it by typing in terminal `group` and it will show what groups you belong to.

Next thing, you can actually change the user background the hard way. There is a profile folder for each user stored in /var/lib/AccountsService/users. For instance, /var/lib/AccountsService/users/sergiy is my account profile. What you can do is to edit that file with the text editor of your choice. I prefer nano. So what I type is this:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/AccountsService/users/sergiy
```

It will prompt for your password (considering that you're in sudoer group, of course) and open the file. Locate line starting with `[User]` and line saying `Background` . Paste the path to your desired wallpaper after = sign. For instance, here's mine:
[image]

After you're done editing , reboot.

And one more thing, I've discovered that file  org.freedestop.Accounts.service prevents changes to greeter backgrounds, and most likely to user backgrounds. So try editing this file with a text editor to comment out Exec line. Again, for me this is

```
sudo nano /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.Accounts.service
```

Change `Exec=/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon` to `# Exec=/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon`

Try this first, and let me know if this helps. I've discovered that after commenting out that line, I was able to change lightdm-gtk greeter background, while previously I could not - it would just override whatever settings I placed into lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf, and show my desktop background instead of the image i wanted.

Note: keep in mind that the first solution I posted, will only work if that Exec line is active, not commented out. Second solution, disables Accounts service

Let me know if this helps. Cheers

Comment: I tried the second option and it didn't work.

Comment: Okay.  What about first one?  Try first solution with commented out and not commented Exec line.

Comment: It only changed my loginscreen. When I logged in, the old wallpaper reappeared. I doubled checked the exec line was uncommented.

Comment: Weird.  So i guess something is overriding your Accounts Service settings once you log in , because initially Accounts Service works properly. The big question is what does the override?  I know you mentioned you had Cinnamon desktop. What desktop you have now?  When you uninstalled did you set your current desktop as default?  It's done through sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm, where lightdm you could substitute you current desktop name.  You'll have menu show up asking to choose default desktop.  Once you choose,  it updates settings.  Reboot.

Comment: No, it didn't work. I entered sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm command but it did not show any menus. Another weird thing that might help is that the rotating wallpaper option of cinnamon is still there. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Try one more thing.  Open startup application (you can find it through dash) and see if cinnamon is still set to start on boot.  Also,  some apps are hidden in this menu.  Here's how to make them show up;https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShowHiddenStartupApplications

Comment: Nope, nothing weird. There was a caribou app but It appears it has nothing to do with this. The other ones were just normal. If you still have some possible solutions, share them! I'm eager to work this out.

Comment: Actually I'm running out of ideas by now.  Here's a fresh post I saw on the same topic.  Check it out. http://askubuntu.com/questions/531743/the-gsettings-command-line-tool-doesnt-change-the-background

Comment: The solution posted there worked! Yeah! :) It seems I didn't have the permission to make changes....

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after I installed cinnamon, had to remove it.  Wish I could comment.

Comment: I installed cinnamon some time ago, it must be that. But I think it's not completely uninstalled, because the problem persist.

Comment: @daniel: I think this is a valid answer.

Comment: I can't help you there, I just wiped ubuntu and reinstalled.  I probably could have removed cinnamon but never figured out how to, or I didn't want to take the time to figure it out.  It was basically a fresh install so I just wiped.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try using gnome-tweak-tool: in "Desktop" tab, toggle "Icons on Desktop" On. Now you can change wallpaper through "Background Location" option, or even using Ubuntu System Settings -> Appreance (that previously was only changing login screen wallpaper). At the end, you can toggle it off, again, if you like.