# Disabling Power Saving features via command line

Tags: command-line, 20.04, power-management, kiosk

I manage a number of remote kiosk systems. After upgrading to 20.04 Desktop, I believe some issues are being caused by some of the power saving features that can be disabled via the Settings > Power control panel, but for these systems I only have command line access.

Is there a way to disable these (in particular Automatic Brightness, Dim Screen While Inactive, and Automatic Suspend) from the command line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many of the settings of the Gnome Desktop are configured through dconf. You can see all possible settings if you install the graphical tool `dconf-editor`. If you know the settings, you can control them using the `gsettings` command:

To disable automatic brightness:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false
```

To disable dim screen while inactive:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

To disable automatic suspend:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
```

To undo, i.e., reset these settings to default, run the same commands, substituting `reset` instead of `set`, and leaving out the last argument.

Comment: Thank you! This was perfect!

Answer (score 10):

I believe you can disable the DPMS or Display Power Management Signaling from the command line.

First to check if it is enabled:

```
xset -q | awk '/DPMS is/ {print $NF}'
```

Example:

```
xset -q | awk '/DPMS is/ {print $NF}'
Enabled
```

To disable it:

```
xset -dpms
```

To enable it:

```
xset dpms
```

Hope this helps!