# Ubuntu 20.04.2 Screen Dims Randomly

Tags: screen, brightness

I have tried all relevant Settings choices, including
"xset s off; xset s noblank; xset -dpms; xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 1.0" as
ordinary user and root, but the screen still dims itself occasionally at random.   How can I permanently turn OFF screen dimming?

There must be some code in the Ubuntu installation to do this!

Maybe something in /etc?

Comment: I've got the same on Dell G15 5515 and Ubuntu 21.10, it just dims randomly without reason

Comment: The problem is in ubuntu power manager upower. But you cannot uninstall it, ubuntu isn't flexible like debian. I'll try to install xcfe4-power-manager on top of it and see if would help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I opened a bug on ubuntu's launchpad. Hoping they fix it.

Interestingly the bug stopped happening on this particular kernel version: 5.11.0-16-generic. Now it's back again.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1938477

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Be sure to only post real answers to the poster's question in the Answer section.

Comment: Even if this post doesn't provide a solution, I find it provides further valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Ubuntu help-page, it seems there are some settings that you can check in the Power Saving section of the Power settings.

Per official Ubuntu helppage: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-whydim.html.en

> If it is possible to set the brightness of your screen, it will dim
> when the computer is idle in order to save power. When you start using
> the computer again, the screen will brighten.
>
> To stop the screen from dimming itself:
>
> ```
> Open the Activities overview and start typing Power.
>
> Click Power to open the panel.
>
> Switch the Dim Screen When Inactive switch to off in the Power Saving section.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already run "Power" and tried all the displayed commands -- no matter what I do, my screen dims (including while running "power")!  I need some info on HOW the various CLAIMED power-control commands control my computer.

Comment: Have you seen this answer by @vanadium ? I assume you're using the default Ubuntu with Gnome, unless you're using another desktop environment?

https://askubuntu.com/a/1346130/1074455

Comment: I tried running the four screen-disablers listed there - my screen still dims uncontrollably.   There is something in my OS which is wrong, but I don't know what.   I suspect there is something in /etc  or /var involved . . ..

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu (same  v. 20.04.2 LTS), but the uncontrolled dimming STILL occurs.   Power setting is "Blank Screen = never"; Screen Lock is "Blank Screen Delay = never", with everything else off.   What controlls this screen dimming?   There must be some command somewhere which can be disabled or removed!

Comment: NOTE:  I have no "Dim Screen When Inactive switch" in my Power directory, which has no "Power Saving" section.   Can this section be installed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a perspective hasn't been discussed yet in this post, you might just have a setting that you don't want. You may have automatic brightness on, which changes the brightness depending on how bright the space around you is. In my opinion, ubuntu isn't the best at it, and it doesn't do it smoothly. This is made for laptops, so if you have a desktop, it's pointless.

You can change this in the settings app, under brightness.

Comment: That fixed it:  I changer the (LG) screen brightness to 45%,   Now everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here!
Kubuntu 20.04 dims randomly, even I have all the power saving options disabled.
I noticed some strange things in this behaviour:

- When de screen dims, if I go to "Power saving" options, if I move slightly or touch a little bit the brightness slider (which is correctly set top right) and click Apply, the screen returns back to its normal brightness.
  [Brightness slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASW9L.png)
- When the screen its also wrongly dimmed, if I increase the brightness using the function keys on my keyboard, it returns to its brightness, but from then on the brightness indicator keeps appearing randomly on screen.
  [Brightness indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gigc.png)
  I wonder if all the problem will be related to my Graphics card controller module: amdgpu. When I hadn't this module installed, my laptop was unusable: very low resolution and many other problems I don't remember. My graphics card is reported by lspci as a "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c3)"

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - while this information is useful, I think it should really have been made as a comment on the question and not an answer. Posting it as an answer that doesn't solve the problem risks people downvoting you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1227374)

Answer (score 0):

I am using kubuntu 22 and in my case I have detected that the system set dynamic contrast option in the configuration of my additional monitor. I uncheked the option and that corrects the dim behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Editing `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf` to ignore `Video Bus` resolved the problem I had on Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 where my laptop LCD screen brightness changed randomly every few seconds.

Add the section below to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Spooky Ghosts"
        MatchProduct "Video Bus"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

I found this solution discussed here:
[random event changes screen brightness automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793829/random-event-changes-screen-brightness-automatically)