# What starts accounts-daemon?

Tags: command-line, upstart, services, init

Question is simple: what starts the accounts service daemon on Ubuntu 14.04?

```
root     11495     1  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
```

`pstree` tells me that it's started by init

```
init-+-ModemManager---2*[{ModemManager}]
     |-NetworkManager-+-dhclient
     |                |-dnsmasq
     |                `-3*[{NetworkManager}]
     |-accounts-daemon---2*[{accounts-daemon}]
```

But when I do `sudo grep -iR 'accounts-daemon' /etc/*` it returns nothing, so obviously there is nothing in `/etc/init` or `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc*.d` directories that starts that daemon, hence the question, where is it ?

My main goal is to disable autostart of the accounts services daemon on boot.

Comment: First observation: Very high PID, therefore it may be something later in bootup.  Perhaps a script in init.d calls something else which calls the daemon?

Comment: If you just want to disable it, track it down and change the executable filename

Comment: And maybe replace it with a simple `false`.

Comment: @Daniel well, I considered disabling the filename, but i would like to do it the clean, honest way. Also, it's quite possible it's a chain of scripts, but at least it's nowhere in the `/etc` folder

Comment: I would at least try changing the filename, because if nothing else you could see what errors get thrown.  Whatever calls it should complain about not finding it

Comment: Why did you want to disable it? On my system it seemed to be the cause of high memory usage in things like `unity-settings-daemon` and `sound-indicator-service`.

Comment: @skerit It's actually a sort of ironic story. The big purpose was to allow setting permanent wallpaper on the login screen (also known as greeter).   When you flip through list of users there, dbus polls accounts daemon, and displays what is set in user preferences.  However, I've forgotten that I've posted a solution to my own problem and forgot about it [about a year ago](http://askubuntu.com/a/529852/295286). During my research I've been aware that accounts daemon was taking high memory usage. AFAIK there have been patches released in newer versions just for that.

Comment: As for wallpaper part . . . I've learned that with `unity-greeter` you can recompile a specific glib schema and for `lightdm-gtk-greeter` it is sufficient to disable showing usernames on the login screen, so user has to type in manually username and password. That will prevent polling accounts daemon and revert to settings in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` I even wrote script sfor that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a DBUS service.

```
root@user-VirtualBox:~# grep -ir accounts-daemon /usr /etc
Binary file /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon matches
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.Accounts.service:Exec=/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
```

Another way:

```
root@user-VirtualBox:~# dpkg -S /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
accountsservice: /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon

root@user-VirtualBox:~# dpkg -L accountsservice
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/dbus-1
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.Accounts.service
/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces
/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/org.freedesktop.Accounts.xml
/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/org.freedesktop.Accounts.User.xml
...
```

To disable it, rename DBUS service file:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.Accounts.service /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.Accounts.service.disabled
```

Comment: Does the job, after reboot no process `accounts-daemon`. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way...

To get the filename:

```
$ ps aux | grep -i accounts-daemon
root       718  5.6  0.7 398588 121280 ?       Rsl  Jan11 151:58 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
```

Stop it and remove accountsservice package by running:

```
sudo service accounts-daemon stop
sudo apt remove accountsservice
```

It will also remove package `user-manager`, but do not worry about it :)

Additional info:

```
Package: accountsservice
Description: query and manipulate user account information
Package: user-manager
Description: user management tool for the Plasma workspace
```

Comment: This worked for me, saving around 1G RAM and 100% CPU from a 2 CPU machine. Thanks!